# Create and Fetch Dynamic url using Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic-url

I have a page `single-colur.html` and it can take a variety of set query strings as can be seen below:

```
single-colur.html?id=1
single-colur.html?id=2
single-colur.html?id=3
single-colur.html?id=4
```

The `id` above is referenced to a `colour` table which has the following columns:

```
id
name
content
```

When people come to `single-colur.html` and they request a specific ID, I'd like to get the respective ID from the URL and send an AJAX request to a PHP page which will get the corresponding row from my table based on the ID that is provided, this is currently implemented.

My question is:  Is it possible that if someone goes to `single-colur.html?id=1` then all the data is fetched and displayed in a new URL based on the `name` field which is referenced by the ID e.g. `single-colur.html?id=1` points you to a dynamically created file called `red.html` and it shows the data from the `colour` table for this ID?

My restriction is that I must create the new file dynamically and it cannot be done statically.

> EDIT

Currently i have two pages .

1)**archive-colour.html**

2)**single-colour.html**

in **archive-colour.html**

```
<div>

 <a href="single-colour.html?id=1">Red</a>
 <a href="single-colour.html?id=2">Green</a>
 <a href="single-colour.html?id=3">Blue</a>

</div>
```

in **single-colur.html?id=anynumber**

```
<div class="result">

</div>
```

In *single-colur.html* i am doing  *ajax* and fetch details from database using requested id and display in class **result** .

This is the current process . But what i need is

in single-colur.html?id=anynumber

i have to replace the current page url with colour-name.html

and show the details . [BUT the thing is ***there is no colour-name.html page in server*** . ie there is no **red.html**, **green.html**,**blue.html** in server . It have to be virtually created by jquery . ]

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: why not using in php `$_REQUEST['id']` etc.

Comment: @mooga how would that help?

Comment: im not sure what this is doing, nor what the question is :( - please tell what you are trying to achieve, or what problem you need to solve

Comment: @Script47 , could you please help to explain my question in good way . Because from i can understand that you already understand the concept .

Comment: @abilasher I have updated your question however, you must include the relevant code and information such as your existing coded attempt. Secondly, there are better ways to achieve this rather than creating a new page, you can do it all through one page and return the JSON response of the table information and output it in a div.

Comment: @Script47 the question is well explained now .Thank you very much

Comment: @abilasher I read through everything, all the comments,and it's still not clear what you want to have happen. Some of this almost sounds like you are looking for URL Redirection, but then you're talking about making an AJAX call to gather the new HTML. Could you explain what you are trying to accomplish, not in code, but in a higher level.

Comment: @Twisty Please see the edits

Comment: @abilasher if this is all being done via AJAX, why do you need `red.html` etc? Do you want the browser to navigate to a page called red.html that does not exist (created dynamically)? Please clarify.

Comment: yes .browser to navigate to a page called red.html that does not exist (created dynamically) . This what i want .

Answer (score 1):

Use Ajax :

```
$.ajax({
  url: "my-colours.html",
  type: "get", //send it through get method
  data: { 
    id: //<Your id here >
  },
  success: function(response) {
    window.location.href = '/' + response.color + '.html' ;
  },
  error: function() {
    //Do Something to handle error
  }
});
```

I suppose this is what you're looking for. Here a dynamic link will be created by ajax and you can give a dynamic value to Id each time.

Comment: `window.location.href` wont work, since he wants to stay on the page hes on. so he has to [modyfy url without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: But he didn't mention anything about reloading. _all the data is fetched and displayed in a new URL based on the name_

Comment: _My restriction is that I must create the new file dynamically and it cannot be done statically._ As far as i can tell this means the file does not actually exists. To content gets loaded from db via ajax and shown in a container - the url changes then to whatever. So it just **looks like** its a static+existing page

Comment: So I guess he must create a page in the server side with dynamic content and send it as response each time with the same name.

Comment: here you created dynamic link , that's correct. What about the content in that dynamic link ? How i can insert content to that dynamic link ?

Comment: inside the data object, set different content you want to send to the server.

Answer (score 0):

So you use

```
window.location = window.location.hostname + "here put the returned from ajax" + ".html";
```

**Explain**

```
window.location.hostname
```

returns the website url

Comment: sorry friend , you didnt understand my point . Actualy my point is how to create virtual / dynamic url . Its not about fetching content using php or jquery .

Comment: if some one click my-colours.html?id=1  , so display data in red.html

Comment: aha, so ajax return what ? `red` ?

Comment: so you want to change the browsers address-bar to `domain.com/red.html` ?

Comment: yes :) . that i want ,and show the corresponding data in red.html

Comment: Take a look [Modify URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) :)

Answer (score 0):

This **example** is as complete as it can be in this environment.

- Load on click via ajax
- Set content
- Set virtual url

```js
$( 'a.virtual' ).click( function( e ) {
  var link = $(this);
  console.log( "Loading: " + link.attr('href') );
  $.ajax({
    url: link.attr('href'),
    type: "get",
    success: function(response) {
      // parse json or howerver data get transferred
      var result = parseJSON(response);
      var content = result['content'];
      var virtual_url = result['url'];

      // set content
      $('#content').html( content );

      // set virtual url
      window.history.pushState([], 'Title', virtual_url);
    }
  });
  
  // do not follow the link!
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a class="virtual" href="my-colours.html?id=1">Link A</a></li>
  <li><a class="virtual"  href="my-colours.html?id=2">Link B</a></li>
  <li><a class="virtual"  href="my-colours.html?id=3">Link C</a></li>
  <li><a class="virtual"  href="my-colours.html?id=4">Link D</a></li>
<ul>
<br/>
Content delivered via ajax:<br/>
<div id='content'>
</div>
```